# Redirect files designed to be in root to subdirectory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried many of the suggestions here for similar questions, but they either break things or make no difference, so please forgive me for not being able to figure things out.

I have some files for a booking app that were designed to go in the domain root, but as I have a Wordpress install there, I put them in a subdirectory (booking-app) instead so that http://somesite.com/booking-app brings up the booking page.

Some of the elements used by the app aren't showing up correctly and I'm guessing that's because the paths referenced in the various PHP files are now slightly out. The app has a .htaccess file that came with it and that is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

What would I have to change so that having the files reside in the subfolder still works? For example, one of the PHP files has the following code:

```
// hack around with the include paths a bit so the library 'just works'
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());



require_once 'oauth.php';
require_once 'curl.php';
require_once 'api.php';
require_once 'bookings.php';
require_once 'account.php';
require_once 'location_search.php';
require_once 'fare_calculation.php';
require_once 'vehicles.php';
require_once 'drivers.php';
```

I'm guessing those files will not be found correctly if not relative to root.

Comment: What's the URL of one of the paths that don't work?

Comment: Have edited the original post to include more info.